# Is the phrase: "...obtained bipartisan political support for the project" redundant?

Tags: adjectives, formality, politics

It appears that bipartisan does not solely refer to political parties, rather just support by two parties. However, would adding political after the phrase be redundant in nature, or more descriptive?

Comment: What have different dictionaries told you?

Comment: You seem to be a native speaker so your question surprises me. bipartisan in American English only refers to political parties (the Democrats and Republicans). Bipartisan support is always political in American English.

Comment: Do you have examples where "bipartisan" is used to refer to something other than political parties? I think you may be confusing it with "bilateral".

Comment: [CACD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bipartisan) has '**bipartisan**: involving or having the support of both sides, especially of political parties'. One assumes that prior context would have spelled out any non-political groups involved, in line with the Gricean maxim of quantity, so the 'political' _should_ not be necessary to ensure the default reading. But it's not ungrammatical to add it.

Comment: As @Barmar indicated it, in a non political context, you would use different words like "bipartite", e.g. *a bipartite agreement between syndicates and employers*.

Comment: Bipartisan support—that is, support by people of more than one political party—when the issue is not political (for some meaning of the word political).  Some issues are non-partisan (or should be).  Conclusion: not redundant.

Comment: You could have bipartisan non-political support: not everything a parliament or legislature does is concerned with politics. (Although being bipartisan and being political are often mutually exclusive.)

Comment: @StuartF politics = "the activities associated with governance". By that definition, practically everything the governing body does is related to politics. There may be occassionally exceptions, like a proposal to wish someone a happy birthday.

Comment: Anyway, if the context of the sentence is already discussing politics or governance, "political" is redundant just on that basis.